# Covert BLE Service Assigned Number From Hex To UUID Format

Tags: android, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, bluetooth-gatt

I'm trying scan for BLE devices with specific Services UUID. I can get the GATT Services values from [GATT Services](http://GATTServices) in hex format. For example `0x1822` is the assigned number for Pulse Oximeter Service. Now I need to convert the hex value to UUID format for example `0x1822` become `0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`

Edit-8/27/2019: I have found [Bluetooth GATT Services & Characteristics](https://gist.github.com/sam016/4abe921b5a9ee27f67b3686910293026#file-allgattcharacteristics-java) repository that contains all GATT services and characteristics

Comment: I don't get your problem? To build the string 00001822-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb from the integer 0x1822?

Comment: @Emil How i can convert `0x1822` to string value `00001822-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` ?

Comment: String.format("0000%04x-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", 0x1822)